# Disable alert of vitamio

Tags: android, alert, vitamio

I have a problem with the `vitamio` library in android studio ,
when i'm using `SDK >23` it show me an error like :

[image]
the error is showed one time while the application is executed and not finished.

I'm searching to disable this alert because it doesn't stop or interomp my application.
is there any where to disable the alert ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using using a native library that is directly accessing private APIs.

> Private API (Enforced since API 24)
>        Native libraries must use only public API and must not link against non-NDK platform libraries. Starting with
>   API 24 this rule is enforced and applications are no longer able to
>   load non-NDK platform libraries. The rule is enforced by the dynamic
>   linker, so non-public libraries are not accessible regardless of the
>   way code tries to load them: System.loadLibrary(...), DT_NEEDED
>   entries, and direct calls to dlopen(...) will fail in exactly the same
>   way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , so there is no possibility to do it ?